# Firebase google-services.json with multiple projects?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics-sdk

For our app I am using two different firebase projects:

- Live: Contains the live iOS & Android app
- Test: Contains all our iOS & Android testing apps

As far as I could see the google-services.json (Android) contains the firebase project information and all related apps (as "client"). Is it supported to add a second "project_info" into this file?

Comment: Why do you need to add two projects into the services.json file ? use case?

Comment: We have 3 different testing apps and one production app. If the app marketing manager wants to send a notification, he or she always has to choose the production app out of 4 apps... that results to a really bad user experience in the firebase console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you try android application flavors, for that
Google just included support for flavors on version 2.0 of the play services plugin. Since this version of the `gradle plugin com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3`

you can do this

app/src/
flavor1/google-services.json
flavor2/google-services.json
Version 3.0.0 of the plugin will search for the json file in these locations (considering you have a flavor flavor1 and a build type debug):

```
/app/src/flavor1/google-services.json
/app/src/flavor1/debug/google-services.json
/app/src/debug/google-services.json
/app/src/debug/flavor1/google-services.json
/app/google-services.json
```

This worked for me even using flavorDimensions. I have free & paid in one dimension and Mock & Prod in the other dimension. I also have 3 buildTypes: debug, release and staging.

How many google-services.json files will depend on your project's characteristics, but you will need at least one json file for every Google project.

If you want more details about what this plugin does with these json files, here it is: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-165824720

Link to the official docs: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

And go here to check the latest version of this plugin: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view

Comment: Thanks Himesh! I was not aware that google-services supports build types & flavors

Comment: One hint for the community: this works also for other files such as Java files. They are merged together by the Gradle build.